# REST in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, rest

Is REST supported in Magento Enterprise 1.9? We need to create some REST web services for Magento and we have to stick to 1.9. I can't find any specific documentation on this.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: NO.
The REST API is available starting Magento CE 1.7 and it's corresponding EE version 1.12.
EE 1.9 has a correspondence with CE 1.4. So...no.
You might consider upgrading.

Answer (score -2):

**The** magento 1.9 (community) has support to REST API I'm use since 1.7(community).

Go to Admin Panel: *System > Web Services*

For example: if you need import all products from ERP data base for magento data base. You can use this implementation:app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Api2/Product/Rest/Admin/V1.php

See this implementation here: http://digitalblend-cl.com/blog/index.php/articles/website-documents/207-magento-rest-and-oauth-to-the-party

In Magento 1.7.0.2 (oAuth 1.2.2) now i'm trying use on 1.9.x: (oAuth 1.2.3)

I think that is more hard install and configure oAuth on Linux... comparing with implementation code